# invoking directive controller method from another directive's controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive `DirectiveA` which has a method `x` defined inside its controller. I need to invoke this method from another directive's (`DirectiveB`) controller.

The problem is with the app I work on because when you need to go to a specific route, you basically invoke another directive which is then rendered by Angular. What I am looking for is to find a way to call `x` method after the page was rendered. That `x` is going to display an element on my page when it is called.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: use  'require' in directiveB to call directiveA. In your 'link' in directiveB, you can add directiveACtrl as the 4th parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use events, you can fire event up the scope by using `$emit`, or down by using `$broadcast`. You catch/subscribe the event using the `$on` listener.

So, on your directive's controller you'll listen to the event (You can also subscribe `$rootScope` but then you need to manually unbind the listener upon directive destroy)

```
$scope.$on('mySpecialEvent', function (event, data) {
   ... DO YOUR STUFF ... 
});
```

And on `DirectiveB` you'll fire the event when you want to execute the action in `DirectiveA`'s listener:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('mySpecialEvent', 'HI');
```